# Feed m4s files directly into SourceBuffer doesn't work

Tags: html5-video, mpeg-dash, dash.js

I downloaded some init MP4 file(init.mp4) and a sequence of m4s files(like 744397965.m4s, 744397966.m4s, 744397967.m4s...) from a live stream http://vm2.dashif.org/livesim/testpic_2s/Manifest.mpd using Dash.js.

Then I tried to feed these files directly into SourceBuffer bind with a video element, no pictures been played and no error thrown, why?

Answer (score 1):

Did you seek the video element to the earliest timestamp in the resultant buffer (if it is not zero) and then call play() ?

Comment: You're right man! I tried to set video.currentTime = sourcebuffer.buffered.start(0), it started to play. Thanks.